# What is an appropriate mathematical term for this combinatorics algorithm?

Tags: combinatorics, terminology, computer-science

**TL;DR:** I am wondering if there is a proper mathematical nomenclature for the instances generated by this algorithm (given that there are unique and specific definitions for the words "permutation" and "combination"):

"You are given a sequence of *n* sets of independently variable size. To generate an "instance," you must select exactly 1 element from each set. Generate all possible instances."

Example given:
( Set A: { 1, 2, 3 }, 
Set B: { 1, 2 } )

This would produce: (1,1),(2,1),(3,1),(1,2),(2,2),(3,2)

**What would these instances be called?**

---

**Details:**

To make that a bit more concrete, the real-world example that led me to write this algorithm is this: my company is selling 2 flavors of health-conscious ice cream, and on the website's order form for this ice cream, we wanted to provide customers with the option of variable quantities up to a maximum of 6 for each.

So, imagine 2 quantity selectors (1 for vanilla, 1 for chocolate), options ranging 0-6. *(In this example, the flavors/selectors are the sets, and the quantities are the objects.)*

A customer could choose (0 vanilla x 1 chocolate), (1 vanilla x 1 chocolate), (2 vanilla x 1 chocolate), etc... these would be the "instances" I am trying to name.

We don't care about the number of sets or the cardinality/size of each set (i.e. it doesn't matter how many flavors we have, nor what the maximum quantity for each would be.)

If anyone is curious, here is the program, written in Javascript: https://jsfiddle.net/ybj90vdn/

Comment: I think you are using the word *set* in two ways here, and some clarity is needed.  First "all possible instances of $n$ sets" suggests you are asking about choosing $n$ different sets (subject to various restrictions).  Then you mention "exactly 1 object is selected from each set".  Probably you can clear things up by separating out what are the "givens" and what are the choices to make in arriving at "instances".

Comment: Sorry, I am pretty ignorant about this stuff and I'm sure there are much better ways to phrase this. (Part of why I included a real-world example.) Is this a better explanation? (and I'll update the OP if you think so) 

"You are given a variable number of sets, each of variable size, and the ability to select a single element from each set at a time. Generate all possible combinations (in a non-technical sense) with these restrictions"
Example given:
Set A: { 1, 2, 3 }
Set B: { 1, 2 }
This would produce: (1,1),(2,1),(3,1),(1,2),(2,2),(3,2)

Comment: To clarify further, you are *required* to select an element from every set in the generation of each combination. (So in my above example, (1) would be an invalid instance, because the fact that there are (2) sets supplied means that every generated instance should include exactly (2) values,1 from each set)

Comment: Interesting to find a mathematician in an ice-cream company :) The closest well-known case is probably the [mathematician in a brewery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/William_Sealy_Gosset) whose distribution we study in statistics class!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Cartesian product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product), [ordered pair](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordered_pair), [tuple](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tuple), and [product type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_type) are all words that you might find relevant. Since I don't know what you want to say, I'm not sure which is best for your use cases.

Comment: Thank you!! Cartesian product sounds exactly like what I'm looking for. :)

Answer (score 0):

I've always used the term "List" for an ordered multi-set. I've heard $n$-tuple also used.

A permutation is generally a 'function' object - it rearranges a list based on indexes, which doesn't seem to be implied by instances. A combination is a subset of some larger set, and hence not ordered like your objects ($(1,2)$ is a different instance than $(2,1)$).